# Expresso Store: Getting all products on sale throws PHP error

Tags: expresso-store

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but the following code gives me a PHP error.

```
{exp:store:search channel="treatments" search:on_sale="yes"}
{exp:store:product
    entry_id="{entry_id}" 
    input:gcc="Gavekort"
    input:msg="Melding"
    input:recipient_name="Mottakernavn"
    input:recipient_email="Mottakers e-post"
}
{/exp:store:product}
```

{/exp:store:search}

Error: **Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /***/expressionengine/third_party/store/src/Store/Tag/SearchTag.php on line 37**

Comment: What version of Store are you using?

Comment: Using version 2.3.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue affecting Store 2.3.1 with PHP 5.3, and will be fixed in the next version.

In the meantime, if you need a quick fix, please replace `$this->ee` with `ee()` on lines 37 and 38 of `third_party/store/src/Store/Tag/SearchTag.php`.